# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError ChunkedInputStream

Tags: java

Below error I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.httpclient.ChunkedInputStream
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a jar dependency issue. Update your question with a screenshot of libs folder or show your pom.xml or dependencies version

please add the below jars in lib if not exists already

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, add the below lines of code just above where the exception is occurring to see from which jar they are referenced in

```
System.out.println(ChunkedInputStream.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```